How can I replace loggly with ElasticSearch?
I have a project in Scala, I currently use loggly to view and get logs such as information, errors, and so on from the project, but we want to replace it with AWS ElasticSearch, do you have any idea how I can start doing that? I'm very new to using AWS.
As additional information, the project uses Java 8 version and SDK 1.8.
These are the current libraries we use in the project:
// Logging libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.26" libraryDependencies += "org.logback-extensions" % "logback-ext-loggly" % "0.1.5" 
Thanks in advance :)
I want to know how I can start using ElasticSearch in a scala project.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
